# From html link in jspx views to entity methods. All generated by Roo

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-roo

All files generated by Roo.  From html link in jspx views to entity methods. But this methods not generated by Roo, I`m write them myself (not Roo) and they not from finders list.

What or may be How? Oo 
I think Roo can`t do this for me. Give me pls some links about best practics to write code.Thnks!

Comment: I mean HOW PRESS HTML LINK & RUN ENTITY METHOD.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the method signature correctly and set the @RequestMapping Attribute also correct. Please share your sample code and I can comment on the same.